# How to duplicate preferred columns data in Conditionally one sheet to multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In My office five Employee is working for example In my office Employ Entry Exit sheet is dere..

**This is Main Sheet**

[image: This is Main Sheet]

Now my requirement
category wise data copy to this sheet to other sheet but it's do it automatically 

 ***Like Example*** 

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGPZF.png)

[image]

Comment: [`VLOOKUP()`], [`INDEX(MATCH())`], [`IF({NameSource}={SheetName},ROW({NameSource})`] and [`INDIRECT({DesiredColumn}&{NameSourceRow}`]  Take your pick, there's three routes you can study to achieve this to just name a few...

Comment: Hi i am very poor in excel i don't Understand kindly let me explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am interpreting your question correctly, but please let me know if I have misinterpreted your request.

Try the following code on your sheet:

```
Sub AutoCopyByName()

Dim Names() As String
Dim i As Long, NumRows As Long, NameRow() As Long
Dim j As Integer, NumNames As Integer

j = 0
NumSites = 0

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''COUNT NUMBER OF ROWS WITH INFORMATION'''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
i = 2 'Standard Counter (counts all non-blank cells)
NumRows = 1 'Number of rows with information
Do While WorksheetFunction.IsText(Sheets("data").Range("A" & i))
    If Sheets("data").Range("A" & i) <> " " Then NumRows = NumRows + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''COUNT NUMBER OF NAMES'''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For i = 3 To NumRows + 1
    If Sheets("data").Cells(i, 1) <> Sheets("data").Cells(i - 1, 1) Then NumNames = NumNames + 1 'Works
Next i

''''''''''''''''''
'''REDIM ARRAYS'''
''''''''''''''''''
ReDim Names(NumNames)
ReDim NameRow(NumNames)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''FINDING THE LOCATION OF EACH NAME IN THE SHEET AND STORING IT IN NameRow ARRAY'''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For i = 2 To NumRows + 1
    If Sheets("data").Cells(i, 1) <> Sheets("data").Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Names(j) = Sheets("data").Cells(i, 1).Value
        NameRow(j) = i
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''COPY ENTRIES PER NAME TO EACH SHEET'''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For i = 0 To NumNames - 1
Worksheets.Add
Worksheets(1).Name = Names(i)
Worksheets("data").Rows(1).Copy
Worksheets(Names(i)).Paste
Worksheets("data").Activate
Worksheets("data").Range(Cells(NameRow(i), 1), Cells(NameRow(i + 1) - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets(Names(i)).Activate
Worksheets(Names(i)).Range("A2").Select
Worksheets(Names(i)).Paste

Next i

End Sub
```

I've used the following as my input sheet
[image]